# Google Drive Migration sharing issues

Tags: google-drive-api

We want to migrate all google drive docs from one domain to other domain. While i got some links on how to transfer ownership of files but the sharing of new transferred files is being nullified . Is there any way to preserve sharing properties also while we transfer?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's currently NOT possible.

As noted in [Set file sharing permissions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en), files inherit sharing policy if transferred within same organization of the file owner. As mentioned:

> Files always inherit sharing policy from the organizational unit of the file owner. A file may therefore inherit a new sharing policy if the owner moves to a new organizational unit or if file ownership is transferred to someone in a different organizational unit.

With this, new file owner might need to [share files and folders](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Hope that helps!